# Does Improved Natural Attack (Claw) apply to all my claw attacks?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-creation

I have a totemist who took Improved Natural Attack to boost the damage of the Claws from the Soulmeld Sphinx claws, and then decided to shape a different soulmeld that also gave claw attacks. (In this case, Girralon Arms bound to my Totem chakra.) Does Improved Natural Attack apply?

The way I read the feat, it applies to a subset of natural attacks, such as "claw," which both soulmelds impart when bound to the Totem Chakra. But I would rather have clarification to be sure. Does it apply to all claw attacks or just one source?

Comment: I believe it's in the Monster Manual five or two, a version of Improved Natural Attack exists which improves **all** of a creature's natural attacks. None of them are on-hand for me, though.

Comment: @LitheOhm: I've looked around a fair bit for that, and didn't find it. If you could let me know where it is, I'd be appreciative.

Comment: didnt see it either but I read the feat as applying to a subset like claws.

Comment: I don't have either of those books, but based on an internet search if it wasn't put out after 06-15-2004 it doesn't stand. The MM 3.5 errata decrees a *single* attack form. My bad, perhaps.

Comment: a single attack form? Like Claws? or just a specific set? I often change sets.

Comment: @LitheOhm: If it had a different name, it may still be 3.5 legal, anyway. Plenty of DMs won't allow 3.0 stuff anyway of course, but it might count for something.

Comment: I read it to say one creature's claws, if that's your choice. Polymorphing you're arguably still the same creature, just different forms. But you still use your feats. @KRyan same name. I'm eighty percent certain it was a 3.5 book. Will remember you if I find it again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes.

> ### Feats
>
> #### Prerequisites
>
> Some feats have prerequisites. Your character must have the indicated ability score, class feature, feat, skill, base attack bonus, or other quality designated **in order to select or use that feat.** A character can gain a feat at the same level at which he or she gains the prerequisite.

From the [System Reference Document](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#prerequisites). The same language can be found in the *Player’s Handbook*.

Emphasis mine: you must meet a feat’s prerequisites to choose it, and in order to use it, and beyond that they mean nothing. You don’t lose the feat if you no longer meet its prerequisites, it just goes dormant.

As for Improved Natural Attack itself...

> Choose one of the creature’s **natural attack forms**. The damage for this natural weapon increases by one step[...]

Also from the [SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsterFeats.htm#improvedNaturalAttack), though this feat is found in the *Monster Manual*.

The phrase “natural attack forms” is used, not “natural attacks” or “natural weapons.” It applies to all natural weapons of that form equally.

Comment: +1 correct. If I find which book/date/wording is used for the other variant I was talking about, I'll come back here and comment.